# Password Validation in JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble with my simple password validations.

These are the things that validation does

- check if password is less than 8 characters
- check if it is more than 15 characters
- check if new password and retyped are mismatched

The form submits when two passwords are matched even if **less than or greater than the validations**

Please see my code:

```
function on_submit(dest) {

    var objForm = document.LogonForm;
    var strMissingInfo = "";

    if (dest == 'logon') {

        if (objForm.current.value != "") {

            if (objForm.new1.value.length < 8 || objForm.new1.value.length > 15) {
                strMissingInfo += "\n   Password must be 8 to 15 characters long";

            } else if (objForm.retype.value != objForm.new1.value) {
                strMissingInfo += "\n   Password mismatch!";

            }

            if (strMissingInfo != "") {
                alert(strMissingInfo);

            } else {
                alert(strMissingInfo);
                objForm.action.value = dest;
                objForm.submit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--- HTML Part

```
<input type="password" id="current" name="current"
                                onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 180px"
                                tabindex="1" required/>

<input type="password" id="new1" name="new1"
                                onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 180px"
                                tabindex="2" required />

<input type="password" id="retype" name="retype"
                                onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width: 180px"
                                tabindex="3" required />

<a href="javascript:;">
                    <input id="logonButton" class="submit"
                        type="submit" name="Submit" value="Confirm" tabindex="4"
                        onclick="on_submit('logon')" />
                    </a>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you imposing an upper limit of 15 characters?

Comment: If you are using a button within a form, it will submit by default regardless of what you do with Javascript.  Can you show us how this function is being called?  Also you initially check `current.value` then switch to `new1.value`  Is that intentional?

Comment: I actually have three fields. 1. Current Password 2. New Password 3. Retype Password.

Comment: how is `on_submit` called?

Comment: on click of a button..

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention the alert occuring, my guess is that you are calling this function with a button from within the form.  That will automatically submit the form, regardless of the onclick function, unless you set the type on the button as described in this question: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

```
<input id="logonButton" class="submit"
                    type="button" name="Submit" value="Confirm" tabindex="3"
                    onclick="on_submit('logon')" />
```

Comment: Yes I am calling the function onClick of a submit button. Thanks,,

Comment: ok then you're going to need to add type=button to the markup for that button.  Otherwise it will submit the form automatically.  Your function may or may not work, tough to tell for sure since I don't know what all your variables, are, but its not even running right now :)

Comment: it won't submit even if the validations are satisfied.

Comment: uh huh, well are you sure its hitting the submit statement? Does it do the alert or does it throw an error?  Like I said, I think your function may have other issues, but this was at least the first one.

Comment: it do the alert. I'll check my function again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the form to fail on submission try returning false when validation fails.

```
        if (strMissingInfo != "") {
            alert(strMissingInfo);
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return either `true` (submit the form) or `false` (stop submission) as necessary from the function, and also use `onclick="return on_submit('logon');"` - or even better you should remove it and put `onsubmit="return on_submit('logon');"` on the form itself.

Comment: On my function area, does it have to return anything?

Comment: The bug is still the same. The form submits even if the password is less than 8 or greater than 15.